# Will my reputation decrease if I remove one of my login from my account?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

I am having 2-3 logins for SO account. One of login is from my company login credentials. I will be no longer access to that login.(You can understand what does it mean.)

If I remove that login from `my logins` of SO account then will my reputation removed which was gained from that account? If so, what should I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You only have one account, with one reputation score; the multiple logins just let you access that account. You only need one login to get to the account, so as long as you leave one so you can still login you'll be fine

Comment: ...until that one stops working for some reason and you wish you'd added a backup...

Comment: @Shog9 Personally I think OpenID delegation is the right solution, not sites allowing multiple OpenIDs, but yes, that would be inconvenient

Comment: That works, but as much as I dislike trying to explain multiple OpenIDs sometimes, that would be worse.